# How is it possible to turn an jupyter notebook that uses altair, pandas and ipywidget into workable .py that i can throw into an exist page?

Tags: python, pandas, altair, pythonanywhere

I learned python through IPython Notebooks and scrambled together but I want to know if it is possible to take the notebook and sort of paste it it with its own route? Or can I upload the notebook into pythonanywhere and create a separate app that way?

Comment: All three of those packages work in JupyterLite and so in theory you can host a static page on GitHub or anywhere and then use [Voici](https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voici), which is [Voila](https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voila) + WASM/JupyterLite. Voila allowed Jupyter Notebooks based in ipywidgets to be full web apps. You can get a sense of its abilities looking at the Voila Gallery. A common way to deploy them without setting up the resources yourself is to rely on MyBinder to serve the active content with a full Python kernel running a remote machine. That is indeed how the ...

Comment: <continued> Voila Gallery demos work. Now because JupyterLite and WASM allow the computational resources to be client side in the user's browser via Web Assembly providing the computational ability via Pyodide kernel (as opposed to the `ipykernel`), you can just leave the content on a static-serving site like GitHub's spaces and it will work as a web app on the client machine. No active remote computer needed. No active full remote Python kernel, etc.. You can see it in action by going to [here](https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voici-demo#-try-it-in-your-browser-) where it says ...

Comment: <continued> 'Try it in your browser' and click on that link. Or click [here](https://voila-dashboards.github.io/voici-demo/voici/render/demo.html) to launch directly an app based on [this notebook](https://nbviewer.org/github/voila-dashboards/voici-demo/blob/main/content/demo.ipynb). The demo page guides you through doing that yourself. You'll note **the caution on the main Voici page that this is still considered 'a preview'. This is important!**  It's not as easy as running Voila on MyBinder at the present time. In other words 'Here there may be dragons'. Although you depending on what you..

Comment: <continued> are trying to do, you may be fine. For one example, [I had a somewhat bumpy time of it](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/bouton-voila-sur-jupyterlite/18505/11?u=fomightez) getting a dataframe into the app, but you can see [here](https://fomightez.github.io/voici-demotest/voici/render/test_providing_inside_nb.html) it worked in the end. I have a few other examples you can launch on your machine from [here](https://fomightez.github.io/voici-demotest/voici/tree/index.html). That is hosted as a static site in GitHub's spaces from [here](https://github.com/fomightez/voici-demotest).

Comment: I forgot to add that you can see for yourself that those all work in JupyterLite by going to [here](https://jupyterlite.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and clicking on the orange 'Lab' button in the upper left corner. When that comes up in your browser, double-click on the 'pyodide' directory on the left file navigation panel. The first example notebook in the listing in there is titled 'altair.ipynb'. It uses Pandas, too. The one named 'interactive-widgets.ipynb' demonstrate ipywidgets. Related to all this, you may want to look at [the SymPy Live Shell](https://live.sympy.org/).